# See if a string contains a char and write it out

Tags: c#, arrays, char

I'm a beginner at this and hoping someone can help me.

What I am trying do is check if the character in `char b` exists in `string s`. If it exists, it should write the letter out to the char array at the right index number. If not, then it should write a `-` instead. But this keeps resetting for me every new instance of `char b`. Any ideas?

```
public static void test(char[] h, char b, string s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == b)
        {
            h[i] = b;
            Console.Write(h[i]);
        }
        if (s[i] != b)
        {
            h[i] = '-';
            Console.Write(h[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the length of `h`? Have you initialized it?

Comment: Might be useful to see the code you are using to call this function. Also, examples of expected input and output would help to understand what your requirements are

Comment: Run it in the debugger line-by-line and watch the variables.

Answer (score 4):

#### `.Contains()` method

Try the string.Contains method that would work for you.

```
someString.Contains('c'); // where c can be any character. returns a bool value
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx

#### `.IndexOf()` method

You can try getting the character at the indexNumber of the string too.

```
int index = IndexOf("String here"); // zero based index number... returns int
```

The above mentioed code is a single line code to find the character.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx

**Just for sake of help**

I think you want to search for each *character* in the available **String**. Few days ago, Jon Skeet, told me this one

```
char characterToFind = 'r';
string s = "Hello world!";
int index = 0; // because foreach won't use any int i = 0 method
foreach (char c in s) { // foreach character in the string
  // read the character and post the output
  if(c == characterToFind) {
    Console.Write("Character found at: " + index.ToString());
  }
  index++; // increment
}
```

Comment: I think you are focusing on the wrong aspect of this question. The OP already has working code for checking if the string contains a character... the problem is with something different (which isn't clear from the information provided)

Comment: @musefan, yes I was just adding that one :) I was looking for the MSDN document for this method.

Comment: The problem is to save the letters each run. For example "monkey" and I try the char 'm' I will get "m-----" but the next run if I try 'o' it will be "-o-----". I don't know if it replaces the char each run with a '-' or if it's just vanish after each run.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do the following:

```
string str = "hello world";
str.Contains('h');
```

Comment: OP Was not looking for how to check if a character is in a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
string.IndexOfAny(b) >= 0;
```

It will give you the index of the char that you can store in your array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`str.IndexOf(String char)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  method.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    if(s[i] == b)
    {
        h[i] = b;
    }
    else
    {
        h[i] = '-';
    }

    Console.Write(h[i]);
}
```

(..and actually simplify it further with the ternary operator `?:`, but let's keep things simple). Running it with this as input:

```
var h = new char[16];
test(h, 'p', "purple people");
```

Produces this input:

```
p--p---p--p--
```

..which I think is what you're after.

Comment: Thanks. It's what im after almost. For your example I want it produce the same input the next run too and still have the p in the text. Everytime I try a new char to match it forgots the last or i think replaces it with '-'.

Comment: I have solved everything now, what I had to to was create another array and then change over the values to that one :)